# @end is missing implementation context Xcode Error

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my Quiz screen.m, I get this error:

@implementation BT_screen_quiz ---------> @end is missing implementation context

How do I fix this error?

Do I just delete the code?

Comment: Can you write your .h code here i think you are missing @end in .h file of your class.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=06CL3bqd

Comment: @user1226827 - Amit meant update the question to include the code external references can go away aso he asked for the .h file your link is the .m which we also need but a smaller amount to show the issue.

Comment: This error can be caused by not enclosing your method body with braces (e.g. ending a method with a "}")

Answer (score 2):

Its as easy as putting @end ad the end your code in your file, something like this:

```
@implementation classname
+classMethod {
    // implementation
}
-instanceMethod {
    // implementation
}
@end
```

Comment: Do I add it all the way at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, just the last line, in both .m and .h

Comment: Now I get 3 more errors Missing Context for property implementation declaration

Comment: Can you paste your .h and .m file? I think you are having more errors that we cannot see now

Comment: Put it and the end of the file!

Comment: Can You Tell me where to put it? My ENTIRE .m file is here http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=06CL3bqd

Answer (score 0):

write your code like this:

```
@implementation BT_screen_quiz
@synthesize quizRunning, numberCorrect, numberIncorrect, streak, totalPoints, totalSeconds;
@synthesize currentQuestionIndex, currentQuestionObject, quizDidEnd;
/* quiz controls */
@synthesize startButtonBox, startButton, questionBox, answerButtonBox, paddingTop;p;

@end         
/* quiz runtime properties */
```

Means your all code should be in between `@implementation` and `@end`

Comment: come on chat please because it is not write place to chat

Comment: As i saw you are missing some braces "{"  in you code so please check that all opening and closing braces are present.

Answer (score 0):

try to added @end to the end of your code to solve the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Checking for @end that mysteriously disappears is the obvious answer.

Sometimes though, if you haven't closed a conditional (if, while, etc) statement with a closing } bracket, then you also get this error. Check your {} and [] brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this problem can occur if you erroneously nest one @implementation inside another.